# Como fazer com que o angular reconheça um evento ng-keyup criado dinamicamente no elemento

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Estou criando uma diretiva que deve incluir dinamicamente uma função no evento angular `ng-keyup`, tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

### Diretiva

```
angular.module('app').directive('validar',validar);

validar.$inject = [];

function validar(){
    var diretica = {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
           validador: '&'
        },
        templateUtl: '....html template segue abaixo',[
        link: link  
    };

    return diretiva;


    function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (scope.validator !== undefined) {
            element[0].setAttribute("ng-keyup", "validador()");
        }     
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" />
```

### Problema

Consegui criar o atributo no elemento, porem o angular não executa a função. Quando eu incluo o atributo manualmente no html desta forma tudo funciona.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" ng-keyup="validador()" />
```

Segundo a resposta do Colega, o DOM já foi renderizado quando a minha diretiva inclui o atributo de forma dinâmica, por isso o atributo existe no elemento, mas o angular não o reconhece.

Comment: tentou usar o $scope.$apply() para tentar forcar o angular a atualizar o dom e linkar as props?

Comment: @CaioKoiti ainda não, vou tetar fazer isso, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre porque ele ja rederizou o html final.
Você poderia tentar torcar no lugar de `ng-keyup` adicionar o proprio evento do DOM `onkeyup` desta forma:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    if (scope.validator !== undefined) {
        element[0].onkeyup = validador();
    }     
}
```

Comment: Fiz isso que você disse porem como o onkeyup não é do javascript, percebo que eu só vejo o resultado da função validador, quando há alguma atualização no DOM. Por isso eu queria usar no ng-keyup

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o jquery para pegar colocando o código abaixo dentro do ngOnInit()

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';   
ngOnInit(){
 $(document).keyup(function(r){
      /* Fazer ação */
    })
}
```

Comment: onde ficaria este código?

Comment: Você está utilizando qual versão do Angular? 
Se for do angular 2 em diante no .ts do teu componente.

Comment: Inclusive ao invés de usar o $(document) utiliza o id ou nome do teu input se não em qualquer ponto do documento ele irá executar tua função.

Comment: uso o angularjs

Comment: puts, desculpa. Talvez você possa criar um outro arquivo js e colocar um $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#idinput').keyup(function(r){
      /* Fazer ação */
    }); 
});

E fazer dessa forma. O jquery deve funcionar.